# docker run from systemd service starts but exits immediately, and restarts, but docker run from shell works fine

Tags: centos, systemd, docker

On my CentOS 7.2 box, with Docker 1.10.3, I successfully tested the following (running as root):

```
docker run --name usljavadoc_server -p 80:80 -p 443:443 -v /opt/app/uslJavadoc/:/var/www/html/ -d eboraas/apache
```

Content automatically deployed to `/opt/app/uslJavadoc` was servable from the apache running in the container.

So, my next step was getting this to work with systemd, so I created  `/etc/systemd/system/docker-usljavadoc.service` with the following contents:

```
[Unit]
Description=Apache serving USL Javadoc
Requires=docker.service
After=docker.service

[Service]
TimeoutStartSec=0
Restart=always
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run --name usljavadoc_server -p 80:80 -p 443:443 -v /opt/app/uslJavadoc/:/var/www/html/ -d eboraas/apache
ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker stop -t 2 usljavadoc_server
ExecStopPost=/usr/bin/docker rm -f usljavadoc_server

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

I manually reloaded systemd and started the service.  I verified that the browser on another box could reach the apache process and get the properly served content.  I then rebooted to make sure it works on reboot.  Still worked.

So, I thought I was done.  However, what I noticed when I looked closer is that the service successfully starts, but it exits immediately after starting, and then restarts.  This is happening continuously.  As it's just plain html content being served (a javadoc tree), and that the service immediately restarts, users might not even notice there is a problem, but it definitely shouldn't be doing this.

Any ideas why this "docker run" works fine from the shell, and seems to start fine from systemd, but exits immediately after a couple of seconds?

Comment: Have you tried to increase `TimeoutStartSec` or to omit the option? I could imagine 0 seconds is a little low for any service to start. Furthermore you could take a look at the log output using `journalctl -u docker-usljavadoc` to see if there are any hints.

Comment: I asked this first on the StackOverflow, and realized later it was more appropriate here, but I got a correct answer from that posting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41352271/docker-run-from-systemd-service-starts-but-exits-immediately-and-restarts-but .